# Adding an object inside a FieldArray is not rendering page

Tags: reactjs, redux, rendering

I am using React and Redux. I have FieldArray inside a FieldArray, I want to add child object into an inner array. I have done code changes and  I can see object has been added to inner array but page is not getting re rendered, changes are not reflected on page.

Code changes are as follows:

Main page:
render function

```
 <div>
      <FieldArray name="parentList" component={CustomCom}                                              
      props={this.props}/>
      <br/>
      <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary"
          onClick={event => this.addDoc(mainDTO)}>Add Doc
      </button>
    </div>


    function mapStateToProps(state) {
        return {
             parentList: state.reqReducer.parentList,
        }
    }
```

CustomCom Component
render method

```
   {fields.map((doc, index) => (
     <div className="col-sm-12">
        {doc.childList  && doc.childList  != undefined && doc.childList  .map((childEle, index) => (
         <div>
             <div className="row"> 
               //redux field
             </div>
            <div className="col-sm-4">
              <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary"
                 onClick={event => this.addChild(index, 
                 docs,fields.get(index).childList)}>Add Child
            </button>
         </div>
    </div>
    ))}

   addChild(index, docs, childList){
        this.props.addChild(index, docs, childList);
    }

    function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
        return {
     docs: state.reqReducer.docs,  //same as parentList
     childList: state.reqReducer.childList
    }
    }

//Action
    export function addChild(index, docs, childList) {
        let newChild= {};
        newChild.prop1 = null
        newChild.prop2 = null
        childList.push(newChild)
        docs[index].childList = childList;
        return (dispatch) => {
            dispatch(setDoc(docs));
        }
    }
    

export function setDoc(payload) {
    return {
        type: ADD_DOC,
        payload: payload
    }
}

//Reducer

 case ADD_DOC:
    return {...state, parentList: action.payload};
```

On call of addChild, I am dispatching action ADD_DOC after setting child in the parent list and in turn it will set/update parentList with the newly added child.
I am using parentList in the main page for parent FieldArray.
Please let me know why it is not getting rendered , any guidance would be really helpful.

Thank you.

Update->
Please let me know if I can access child array like this (doc.childList) in main array loop where doc is parent element

```
 {fields.map((doc, index) => (  //Main array traversing
        <div>
            <div className="col-sm-12">
                {doc.childList  && doc.childList != undefined && doc.childList.map((singleChild, index) => (  
                ))}
            </div>
        </div>          
    }
```

Update2:

Component got rendered but doc.childList was giving undefined. Tried to change code

1. -> First Try I had to make changes in code for traversing child array: doc.childList changed to fields.get(index).childList ; now I
   was able to see the childList but code
   fields.get(index).childList.map did not work.
2. -> Second Try Moved Child Array traversing to separate component, it worked. Posting full code as an answer.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to say it appears to be state mutation in your action creator.

```
//Action
export function addChild(index, docs, childList) {
  let newChild= {};
  newChild.prop1 = null
  newChild.prop2 = null
  childList.push(newChild) // <-- mutates state.reqReducer.childList
  docs[index].childList = childList; // <-- mutates state.reqReducer.docs
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(setDoc(docs));
  }
}
```

Generally you want to shallowly copy array element ***and*** also shallowly copy the element properties of the element being updated.

```
//Action
export function addChild(index, docs, childList) {
  const newChild = {
    prop1: null,
    prop2: null,
  };

  // shallow copy childList array and append new child element
  const newChildList = [...childList, newChild];

  // shallow copy docs and update childList property of element matching index
  const newDocs = docs.map((el, i) => i === index ? {
    ...el,
    childList: newChildList,
  } : el);
  
  return (dispatch) => dispatch(setDoc(docs));
}
```

Comment: Thanks Drew, object is updated in the store but again page is still not getting re rendered :(

Comment: @Khushi It's possible you've other state mutations or problems occurring. Can you post complete component and reducer code? Also, if you can get a *running* codesandbox that reproduces this issue that can make debugging easier.

Comment: Thanks Drew for your comment. Let me know one thing here, can I access Child array like this doc.childList in parent array loop where doc is parent element. I have updated question.Can you please check. Thank you.

Comment: @Khushi So long as `state.reqReducer.docs` exists, I don't see why not. Something like `doc.childList && doc.childList.map(..`, the first condition will resolve truthy if `doc.childList` is defined, so the second condition you have above `doc.childList !== undefined` isn't necessary.

Comment: @Khushi Has this sufficiently answered your questions and resolved your issue?

Answer (score 0):

Child Array Component gets rendered from ParentArray loop as follows

```
<div className="col-sm-12">
        <FieldArray name={`${doc}.childList`} component={ChildComponent}/>
  </div>
```

In ChildComponent

```
 <div className="col-sm-12">
        {fields.map((childEle, index) => (
            <div className="col-sm-2">
                <Field component={ReactSingleSelect}
                                                   options=(DTO.childOptions}
                                                   label={"Name"}
                                                   name={`${childEle}.name`}
                                                     />
            </div>    
        ))}
    </div>
```